# How can I use whip/whep functionality of gstreamer in a java application?

Tags: java, gstreamer

"I am developing a Java application that requires the use of Gstreamer's whepsrc and whipsink functionality from the gst-plugin-webrtchttp. Therefore, I am planning to use JNI wrapper and also create my own .so file.
However, I am unsure where to start and it seems like a labor-intensive task to create my own C/C++ file containing the required Gstreamer functionalities.
Do you have any suggestions or tricks that I could use?"

Comment: "gstreamer should not be installed on their system" is a vague requirement. Did you check that you are allowed to bring your own gstreamer installation? If not, did you check that you are *allowed* to use any gstreamer component?